# How can I verify that a file exists in Windows with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server running on my Windows Server and, at a specific column of a table, I have the path for a Zip file (which in turn has the source of the data stored in the database). Some of these are not valid (do not match the data in database). I need to make SQL Server verify that these Zip files exist and that they match the column that stores the path and name of the zip file. This way I will delete the wrong file-path column correspondences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xp_fileexist](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stored+Procedures/xpfileexist/183/) however please note it is undocumented and unsupported.

You can use SQLCLR, however you didn't bother specifying what version of SQL Server you're using, so it may not be relevant - and in any case it is disabled by default, and security policies prevent its use in some places.

You can use a #temp table and xp_cmdshell, however xp_cmdshell is typically disabled for the same reasons as SQLCLR.

```
/* if you need to enable xp_cmdshell:

exec master..sp_configure 'show adv', 1;
reconfigure with override;
exec master..sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
reconfigure with override;
exec master..sp_configure 'show adv', 0;
reconfigure with override;

*/

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
   @file VARCHAR(1000),
   @path VARCHAR(255),
   @cmd  VARCHAR(2048);

SELECT
   @file = 'foo.zip',
   @path = 'C:\wherever\';

SELECT @cmd = 'dir /b "' + @path + @file + '"';

CREATE TABLE #x(a VARCHAR(1255));
INSERT #x EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #x WHERE a = @file)
   PRINT 'file exists';
ELSE
   PRINT 'file does not exist';
DROP TABLE #x;
```

**EDIT** based on new requirements. It shows a list of files either in the table or in the database, and indicates whether the file is in only one location or both. It assumes that path + file is <= 900 characters long (merely to be able to use an index on at least one side).

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.files(f VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT dbo.files(f) SELECT 'zip_that_does_not_exist.zip'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'c:\path\file_that_does_not_exist.zip'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'c:\path\file_that_exists.zip'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'zip_that_exists.zip';

DECLARE 
   @path VARCHAR(255),
   @cmd  VARCHAR(2048);

SELECT
   @path = path_column,
   @cmd  = 'dir /b "' + path_column + '"'
FROM 
   dbo.table_that_holds_path;

CREATE TABLE #x(f VARCHAR(900) UNIQUE);

INSERT #x EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
DELETE #x WHERE f IS NULL;
UPDATE #x SET f = LOWER(f);

WITH f AS 
(
    SELECT f = REPLACE(LOWER(f), LOWER(@path), '')
        FROM dbo.files
)
SELECT 
    [file] = COALESCE(x.f, f.f),
    [status] = CASE 
        WHEN x.f IS NULL THEN 'in database, not in folder'
        WHEN f.f IS NULL THEN 'in folder, not in database'
        ELSE 'in both' END
FROM
    f FULL OUTER JOIN #x AS x
    ON x.f = f.f;

DROP TABLE #x, dbo.files;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answear, just another question. How can I use a value from another table that contains my "@path" to automate this script over all my column?

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder, or could each file be in a different folder? And let me guess, you have the full path in a single column, instead of splitting out the path and file name?

Comment: All the files are in the same folder and each one has (or could have) the full path on database.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the undocumented proc `xp_fileexist`  will return 1 if it exists and 0 otherwise

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @iFileExists INT

EXEC master..xp_fileexist 'c:\bla.txt', 
 @iFileExists OUTPUT

select @iFileExists
```

Comment: Don't you need additional permissions to perform file read operations -- as in permissions you by default do not have when setting up the inital sql accounts?

Comment: xp_fileexist runs under the account that SQL Server is running IIRC, it is used by maintenance jobs and other internal functions